# Pascal. Пробелы в строке

Tags: массивы, строки, pascal, freepascal

Этот код должен выводить фамилию из одного массива, а оценку из другого.
На входе массива фамилий - значения с клавиатуры, а в массиве оценок - случайные числа.
Все работает до тех пор пока не вводишь в качестве элемента массива строк(фамилий) длинную строку содержащую пробел. 
При этом, если вводить короткие строки с пробелом в качестве элемента массива, то все работает норм.

```
program untitle;
uses crt;
var i, k:integer;
    name:array of string;
    mar_arr:array of integer;
    num:integer;
begin
    writeln(' Сколько человек в группе? ');
    readln(k);                              //получаем от пользователя количество учащихся
    setlength(name, k);                     //масиву с учащимися устанавливаем длину
    setlength(mar_arr, k);                  //массив оценок содержит столько же элементов сколько и массив учащихся             
    for i:=1 to length(name) do
        readln(name[i]);
    randomize;  
    for i:=1 to length(name) do begin
        write(name[i]);                     //вывод массива учащихся
        mar_arr[i]:= random(5);             //заполнение массива оценок псевдослучайными числами от 0 до 5
        num:=random(9);                     //это для вывода случайных значений после запятой
        writeln(' - ', mar_arr[i], ',', num);//вывод оценок.
    end;
end.
```

`Ошибка: Runtime error 216 at $00000000004195A8
  $00000000004195A8
  $000000000040018C
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Update 1:04pm: Один раз отработал без ошибки при вводе большой строки с пробелом

Comment: Динамические массивы нумеруются с какого индекса?

Comment: @MBo c 1 до n-1

Comment: @MBo Все понял.

Comment: Какой источник использовался для получения такой интересной информации?

Comment: @MBo Посмотрел источник еще раз. С 0 до n-1. Все работает. Вот [отсюда](http://pascalabc.net/stati-po-pascalabc-net/obuchenie-programmirovaniyu/24-dinamicheskij-ili-staticheskij) информация

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код который не вызовет ошибку:

```
program untitle;
uses crt;
var i, k:integer;
    name:array of string;
    mar_arr:array of integer;
    num:integer;
begin
    writeln(' Сколько человек в группе? ');
    readln(k);                              //получаем от пользователя количество учащихся
    setlength(name, k);                     //масиву с учащимися устанавливаем длину
    setlength(mar_arr, k);                  //массив оценок содержит столько же элементов сколько и массив учащихся             
    `for i:=0 to length(name)-1` do
        readln(name[i]);
    randomize;  
    `for i:=0 to length(name)-1 do begin`
        write(name[i]);                     //вывод массива учащихся
        mar_arr[i]:= random(5);             //заполнение массива оценок псевдослучайными числами от 0 до 5
        num:=random(9);                     //это для вывода случайных значений после запятой
        writeln(' - ', mar_arr[i], ',', num);//вывод оценок.
    end;
end.
```